# How can I recover Ubuntu after accidentally installing another distribution over it?

Tags: installation, data-recovery

I had Ubuntu 10.10 with a sound card problem, and decided to install another distribution to solve it. I tried to tell the new distro to install to another partition, but I must have made a mistake because it installed *over* my existing Ubuntu.

Is there a way to recover all my data? I'm especially interested in the contents of my former home directory.

Comment: f5    f5     f5      f5  f5   f5 f5 f5

Comment: Try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Here are links that might help you [recover files](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=61&front_id=12) and [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you partitioned your Ubuntu installation. If you chose default options then most likely your home folder resided on the same partition as your system. In this case when you installed a new distro on that partition it got fully overwritten. 
I'm afraid there's no way to recover your data? sorry...